# Creating a json in Play/Scala with same keys but different values

Tags: scala, playframework

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
{ "user-list" : {
      "user" : [
           "username" : "foo"
       },

       {
           "username" : "bar"
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Im using play-framework and scala.

Thanks!

Comment: you can't have the same keys but different values. are you talking about an array of values for a key? I think we need to know where your data is coming from to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As previous commenters already pointed out, it is not obvious how to help you, given that your json code is invalid (try [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)) and that we don't know where it comes from (string? (case) classes from a database? literals?) and what you want to do with it.

Valid json code close to yours would be:

```
{
  "user-list": {
    "user": [
      { "username": "foo" },
      { "username": "bar" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Depending on how much additional information your structure contains, the following might be sufficient (V1):

```
{
  "user-list": [
    { "username": "foo" },
    { "username": "bar" }
  ]
}
```

Or even (V2):

```
{ "user-list": ["foo", "bar"] }
```

Following the [Play documentation](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaJson), you should be able to generate V1 with:

```
val jsonObject = Json.toJson(
  Map(
    "user-list" -> Seq(
      toJson(Map("username" -> toJson("foo"))),
      toJson(Map("username" -> toJson("bar")))
    )
  )
)
```

and V2 with:

```
val jsonObject = Json.toJson(
  Map(
    "user-list" -> Seq(toJson("foo"), toJson("bar"))
  )
)
```